# Schannel log cipher suite version incorrect

Tags: ssl, openssl, event-viewer, schannel

I am trying to figure out the cipher suite version used for TLS handshake on a web server.

1. Following [Enable Schannel event logging in Windows and Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/enable-schannel-event-logging), I set the registry to 0x05 (informational, success and error) and can see the logs in Event Viewer.
2. I can also find [Event ID 36880: An SSL (client or server) Handshake Completed Successfully](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786445(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#event-id-36880-an-ssl-client-or-server-handshake-completed-successfully) events wherein I can see something like this:

```
A TLS client handshake completed successfully. The negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows.

   Protocol version: TLS 1.2
   CipherSuite: 0xC030
   Exchange strength: 384 bits
   Context handle: 0xABC
   Target name: x.x.x.x
   Local certificate subject name:
   Remote certificate subject name: CN=*.xyz.com
```

The **CipherSuite version** (0xC030 in this case) is what I am interested in.

To further test if this is working correctly, I used OpenSSL to perform a TLS handshake with a specific cipher suite.

```sh
openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.com:443 -cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256
>
<omitted>
SSL handshake has read 4702 bytes and written 603 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
<omitted>
```

I can see that the handshake was indeed successful. However, on checking the EventViewer, I still see SCHANNEL events with CipherSuite version 0xC030 **instead of the expected 0x009C** (using [Supported cipher suites](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateways/2018.4?topic=scpc-ciphers) to identify the hex value for cipher suites).

Any pointers on why I can't see the correct cipher suite version in EventViewer despite performing handshake with specific cipher suites?

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: I guess you are not connecting directly to the web server, but there is some (reverse) proxy in front of web server. You shoud to provide bigger picture of your infrastructure.

Comment: I also tried making calls to the web server directly (client on the same VM as the web server), I doubt there's a proxy in between :/